# Android RecyclerView Custom Image Displaying

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a **recyclerview** which displays data from an SQLite database.
I have a list of icons that I save in an ArrayList and apply color to them inside the ArrayList too.

```
  Example:         mMoodIcons.add(new MoodIcons(R.drawable.excited_icon,  R.mipmap.background_clouds_excited, ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.excited), mContext.getString(R.string.excited)));
```

In the recycerview I have this code:

```
   if(currentLog.getMoodBefore() == 3){
        holder.moodIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.confident_icon);
        holder.moodIcon.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.confident));
    }
```

I need to make it dynamic so, for example, each mood has a number 1 = happy, 2 = fine, etc

So when the recycler view is displaying the information from the log it can display the correct mood icon with the color applied.

Could someone help me with the logic to write this code? I'm hitting a wall.

EDIT: The way I have it written above works in the if statement. But that would require 18 if statements. Is there a slicker way of writing this, maybe using an arraylist and a for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this myself. I created an arraylist of the mood icons and colors. Then I used this code:

```
 for (MoodIconsWorkoutLog moodBefore : moodIcons) {

        if(moodBefore.getMoodBefore() == currentLog.getMoodBefore() ){
            holder.moodIcon.setImageResource(moodBefore.getMoodImage());
            holder.moodIcon.setColorFilter(moodBefore.getColour());
        }
    }
```

Worked perfectly